# Every time I add a new mesh it goes behind the background image, how to make it on top?

Tags: modeling

I have a background image on the side view angle, I added a new mesh to model a part of my image but can't for the life of me put the background image behind the mesh...

Edit: Solved it, Depth parameter of the image was set to Front, I have set it to default and it took care of the issue, thank you

Comment: Hi! Could you please edit your question to be more specific? A screenshot of the problem might be helpful in understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

New objects are created at the location of your 3D cursor. You can <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ Right-click to position your cursor. Alternatively, edit its 3D corrdinates in the 3D cursor popover menu:

[image: 3D Cursor Menu]

Comment: doesn't work, I put the 3d cursor, supposedly, in front of the backgorund image, I create a mesh in that point, and still the mesh is behind the background image on the side view, even though its beside it on the front view...

Comment: Solved it, Depth parameter of the image was set to Front, I have set it to default and it took care of the issue, thanks